# Firebase Realtime DB Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Does anyone know if it possible to parse a value trying to be written to the DB?

EX.

```
".write" : "(root.child('Game/' + newData.val().replace(':%d', '') + '/isPlayed').val() == false)"
```

the input would: `2022090800:29`

So I would like to remove everything at and past the `:29`

OR can I only do the evaluation on the first 10 chars of the value with the following:

```
".write" : "(root.child('Game/' + newData.val().length(10) + '/isPlayed').val() == false)"
```

Comment: I don't see any `split(":")` like functionality mentioned in the documentation. Can you explain what the use case is? There might be some way to do it perhaps by changing the `:` logic?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I need to verify that the game is not 'played'. So the value being written to the database includes both the game id `2022090800` separated by the `:` followed by the team id `29`. So my validation is trying to see if the game in NOT played in order for the user to write their data to the node.

Comment: Is there any reason to store both game ID and team ID in a single field? I would recommend storing them separately (irrespective of which database you are using).

Comment: thats a mute point now. Now I would like to know if its possible to parse the newData.val()

Comment: No, [`replace()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#replacesubstring_replacement) does not support Regex like Firestore's `replace()` as per the docs.